# How to filter users using UserProfile field in Django 1.7?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am using Django 1.7, Pyton 3.4 and PostgreSQL 9.1.
I have problem with filtering users using field from UserProfile.
Here is my UserProfile in models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    is_agency = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)
    customer_linked = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, blank=True)
```

I can add now new user, but I would like to display list of users that in profile are 'is_agency' checked and Customer's name that is in ForeignKey.
I am struggling with my view:

```
def agency_list(request):
    users = UserProfile.objects.filter(is_agency = True)
    return render_to_response('agency/list.html', {'users': users}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and my template is:

```
{% for user in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ user.username }}</td> 
        <td> --here Customer's name--</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Any ideas how can I fix my view.py and list.html?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the view as is and change the template to:

```
{% for profile in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ profile.user.username }}</td> 
        <td>{{ profile.customer_linked.name }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Side note: to increase speed and reduce the number of DB hits use the [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) method:

```
users = UserProfile.objects.select_related().filter(is_agency=True)
```